# wild cards in mysql

Tags: mysql, wildcard

I have a MySql table which has a column in below format

```
Topic
=================
|| **A/B/C/D** ||
|| **A/B**     ||
|| **A/B/C**   ||
|| **A/B/E**   ||
|| **A/B/F**   ||
=================
```

What I want exactly is, to get the Topics only till the level I want say I want a list of child topics of B. I should get the list as C, E and F. Note that I shouldn't get the row with both C and D. 
I tried using 
select distinct(Topic) from db.table where Topic like 'A/B/%';

But I am getting all the records with all levels till D in my case which I don't need.

I am not sure how to do it in MySql. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT *
    FROM db.table
    WHERE Topic LIKE '**A/B/_**'
```

Based from [MySQL's Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html):

> use “_” to match any single character and “%” to match an arbitrary
>   number of characters (including zero characters)

The query above only matches any **single** character. So we can use it only if we know the length of characters that we want to match.

Otherwise, we will have to use [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).

But take note that a better database design can fix your problem easier. Check if you can normalize your table so you can query your records smoothly.

Comment: Hi @KaeL I tried different regexes as you told but none worked for my case unfortunately :( Anyways I have taken a different approach to the problem and worked it around in my code. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated